# Greek Symbols in box and circle

Tags: greek

When I use `\fbox{T}` I can write alphabet in a box. But I get error lets say if i try `\fbox{\mu}`, the error is

```
! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>
```

So my aim finally is to write Greek symbols in boxes and circles. Please help. Also want to know what's the command for drawing circle around text.

Comment: Use `\fbox{$\mu$}`. [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\fbox` makes the interior to be in text mode and `\mu` should be used in `math` mode. Hence as told by Karl, you should be using `$\mu$` inside (not just `\mu`). For circled text, you can use `\textcircled` from `textcomp` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{$\mu$}\textcircled{$\mu$}
\end{document}
```

If you want colors, there is always `tikz` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mycircled}[2][none]{%
 \tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt,fill=#1](a){\ensuremath #2\strut};
 }
\begin{document}
  \mycircled{$\mu$} \mycircled[red!30]{\alpha}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\textcircled` is available without `textcomp` too (thanks to Karl Koeller for the remainder) but with `textcomp` it is well drawn and looks good.

Comment: @physicist You are welcome. :)