# How to cross-out a number several times?

Tags: cancel

[image]
Hello. I want to be able to cross out a number several times (just like in the picture!) at least 3 times. How do i do that? And how do i make a circle around a number?

Comment: welcome! it's courtesy to provide a MWE to show the effort you made. see http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-minxampl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crossout commands are `\crossout`, `\dcrossout`, `\tcrossout`, and `\qcrossout`, for 1,2, 3, and 4 strokes respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\rawcrossout[2]{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{#2}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}
\def\XX{\kern-3pt/}
\newcommand\crossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{/}}
\newcommand\dcrossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{/\XX}}
\newcommand\tcrossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{/\XX\XX}}
\newcommand\qcrossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{/\XX\XX\XX}}
\newcommand\shadowbox[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\makebox[\wd0]{\fbox{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\shadowbox{2} \crossout{4} \dcrossout{6} \tcrossout{70} \qcrossout{86}

2 4 6 70 86
\end{document}
```

[image]

While an `\fbox` would typically be used for a boxed quantity, it seemed from the application that you might want one that is the same width as the original number, so I also provide `\shadowbox{}`.

Comment: Thanks, @Pia. For a circled number, you could use the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233011/greek-symbols-in-box-and-circle

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\ooalign` (one of my favorite tools to play with):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\crossout}[2][1]{%
  \vphantom{\rslash}%
  {\ooalign{\hidewidth$\crosses{#1}$\hidewidth\cr$#2$\cr}}%
}

\newcommand{\crosses}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
    \or
    \rslash\or
    \rslash\mskip-5.5mu\rslash\or
    \rslash\mskip-5.5mu\rslash\mskip-5.5mu\rslash%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\rslash}{\raisebox{.15ex}{/}}

\begin{document}

\fbox{$2$} \fbox{$3$} \crossout{4} \fbox{$5$} \crossout[2]{6}
\fbox{$7$} \crossout{8} \crossout{9} \crossout[3]{90}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but there are two flaws.  First, `#2` is going to be typeset in math mode, i.e. in a different font.  Second, because the character to be typeset is in the second “row” of `\ooalign`, the height of the resulting box is determined by the slashes and not by the character, cf. `\fbox{\crossout{\displaystyle\int}}`.

Comment: The definition should thus read something like `\newcommand{\crossout}[2][1]{\vphantom{\rslash#2}{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\crosses{#1}$\hidewidth\cr#2\cr}}}`

Comment: @HenriMenke The slash is certainly bigger than the digits, so the `\vphantom` sets the depth accurately; if you need to use this also for deeper and higher symbols, add `$#2$` in the `\vphantom`. These are numbers used as numbers, so they should be in math mode. I forgot `$` in `\fbox`.