# \cancel: double strike

Tags: cancel

Is it possible to generate multiple `\cancel` stripes? Say for instance I have

```
$f(x,y) = 3x^2 +2xy +4y^2 - 3x^3 - 3x^2 - 2xy + 4xy^3$
```

and I want to cancel the `3x^2`-term once and the `2xy`-term twice.

```
$f(x,y) = 3x^2 +2xy +4y^2 - 3x^3 - 3x^2 - 2xy + 4xy^3$
```

Obviously,

```
$f(x,y) = \cancel{3x^2} +\cancel{\cancel{2xy}} +4y^2 - 3x^3 - \cancel{3x^2} - \cancel{\cancel{2xy}} + 4xy^3$
```

does not work...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313688/how-to-cross-out-a-number-several-times

Comment: If it is to distinguish between cancellations, you might use  `\bcancel`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I knew I recently saw a similar post, but didn't succeed in finding it!

Comment: \bcancel would work, but then the problem poses itself again if i want to cancel *three* pairs of terms.

Comment: Coloured cancel lines?

Comment: Unfortunately my course has to be in black and white only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used my answer at [How to cross-out a number several times?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313688/how-to-cross-out-a-number-several-times) and modified to

**REVISED ANSWER**

1. make it in math mode,
2. auto-stretch the cancel to fit the term size.

Here is the revised MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,amsmath,fp,scalerel}
\newcount\crosswd
\newcount\termwd
\newcommand\rawcrossout[2]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#2$}%
  \crosswd=\wd0\relax%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
  \termwd=\wd0\relax%
  \FPdiv\myscale{\the\termwd}{\the\crosswd}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{#1}{\stretchrel*{\scalebox{\myscale}[1]{#2}}{#1}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\def\XX{\kern-3pt/}
\def\YY{\kern-.5pt}
\newcommand\crossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{\YY/\YY}}
\newcommand\dcrossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{\YY/\XX\YY}}
\newcommand\tcrossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{\YY/\XX\XX\YY}}
\newcommand\qcrossout[1]{\rawcrossout{#1}{\YY/\XX\XX\XX\YY}}
\begin{document}
\[f(x,y) = 3x^2 +2xy +4y^2 - 3x^3 - \crossout{3x^2} - \tcrossout{2xy} + 4xy^3\]

\[
f(x,y) = 3x^2 +2xy +4y^2 - 3x^3 - \dcrossout{3x^2} - \tcrossout{2\dfrac{\partial \psi^{\ast}}{\partial \theta}\dfrac{\sin\theta \cos\theta}{r^2}} + 
\qcrossout{4xy^3}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I used my answer at [How to cross-out a number several times?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313688/how-to-cross-out-a-number-several-times) and modified to

1. make it in math mode,
2. stretch the cancel horizontally by a default amount, and
3. allow an optional argument to respecify the horizontal stretch value.  Thus, for example, `\crossout[3]{3x^2}` could be used to make the 1-stroke cancel wider.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\rawcrossout[3]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{#2}{\scalebox{#1}[1]{#3}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\def\XX{\kern-3pt/}
\newcommand\crossout[2][2.5]{\rawcrossout{#1}{#2}{/}}
\newcommand\dcrossout[2][2.5]{\rawcrossout{#1}{#2}{/\XX}}
\newcommand\tcrossout[2][2.5]{\rawcrossout{#1}{#2}{/\XX\XX}}
\newcommand\qcrossout[2][2.0]{\rawcrossout{#1}{#2}{/\XX\XX\XX}}
\begin{document}
$f(x,y) = 3x^2 +2xy +4y^2 - 3x^3 - \crossout{3x^2} - \dcrossout{2xy} + 4xy^3$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's already a step in the right direction, but unfortunately it doesn't work well with 'larger' expressions. The example I gave here was somewhat artificial, I'd be more interested to be able to double cancel terms of this size:





    $f(x,y) = 3x^2 +2xy +4y^2 - 3x^3 - \dcrossout{3x^2} - \dcrossout{{2\dfrac{\partial \psi^{\ast}}{\partial \theta}\dfrac{\sin\theta \cos\theta}{r^2}}} + 4xy^3$

Oops, I can't get the code to work. I only have a small edit window at my disposal...

Comment: @Werner I could work to make the crossout autoscale to the object size, but then, the appearance would change with the object width/height.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Werner Please see revision.

Comment: The lines are thicker than I'm used to, but the solution's acceptable to me. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @Werner You are welcome.  The strokes can be made slightly thinner by modifiying `\def\XX{\kern-0pt/}`.